# Teradata & Continuous Integration

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, teradata

Status quo:
We are developing a project at the client side. There's an existing Teradata appliance on the DEV side and one on the production side.
On the DEV side there is more than one supplier and every supplier has its own sub-database. The DBAs are not granted with direct permissions but call macros to create users and databases, grant rights etc. But no SYSDBA permissions on Teradata.
On the PRD side these macros don't exist. Every statement has to be run as is and has to be run automatically (packaged via RPM).
Therefore it is currently impossible to do a complete packaging and integration testing.

We have a Jenkins running which is doing several other tasks. The system is virtual, we're root and we already have an established packaging process.

What we need/ideas: an image of a plain Teradata database we can connect to (remote is ok) and run our DDL scripts.
The idea is to start some kind of image (Docker, VMWare, VirtualBox) which provides a small Teradata installation, we run our DDLs and throw the result away at the end.

Best case would be Docker in this case, but I'm open for ideas. Is there some kind of trial Teradata (v15) which can be used in this case?

Comment: The first hits in any web search for *free teradata*, *teradata trial*, etc. will guide you to https://www.teradata.com/products-and-services/teradata-express running on VMWare Player, there's another free version for ESXi.

Comment: Thanks. I found that, too. Running a VMWare image inside an already virtualized server isn't the ideal solution so I wanted to wait if someone has it running in Docker. I found something from Teradata in Docker Hub but no image for the database. --> https://hub.docker.com/u/teradatalabs/

Comment: I don't think there will be a Docker version in the near future (probably never). You can run the Teradata Express on any hardware (ok, you will need 8GB RAM), I use it locally on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into this (as I need to do the same) and here is what I have found:

You can actually run the VMWare image in Virtualbox (which is what I will be doing).
Once I have the image running I tarred and dumped out the file system at root (/) and I was able to startup docker.

However Teradata Express has also got a RAID1 setup (I think) which are the two vmdks PDISK0 and PDISK1 (SCSI sdb and sbc).  I couldn't find a way to replicate this in docker (without spending more time and my time is up on this) so for now I think running in docker is not an option but if someone more familar with docker could find a way to virtualize the RAID1 I am happy to be corrected.

Comment: maybe you could add a few more details from to links to you answer. Once the links are broken, your answer is as well (at least for the non-stackoverflow-link)

Comment: The PDISK0/1 are not Raid1, these are the VDisks assigned to AMPs, i.e. the AMP's *permspace*.